# How do I read from a csv and put that into Chromedriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I load urls from a csv with Chromedriver?

Say I had ever dynamic list in a csv column 1.  So lets say in my list I had:

```
https://www.youtube.com/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6ljFaKRTrI&list=RDY6ljFaKRTrI
```

And I wanted it to:

1) load that from a csv file, navigate to a page, do actions.
2) Navigate to a new page loaded from csv file.  Do actions.

E.g:

```
import csv 
For infinite loop in infinite loops
    with open("C:\\Users\\Hoxtilicious\\3d11.csv", 'r') as data_file:
       reader = csv.reader(data_file, delimiter='\t')
       for row in reader:
          print("Getting %s" % ', '.join(row))
          driver.get(row)

driver.get(row)
#Actions 1, 2
```

Comment: what is the problem ? do you get error message ? Always show full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot)

Comment: @furas Good point, I'll do that now.

Comment: BTW: you have to do action inside `for` loop - directly after `driver.get()`. Or maybe you could run every url in new `thread` but it may need separated browser/driver for every thread.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 'url' must be a string

Comment: @furas Beats me

Comment: `row` is a list. You can't use list as url. You have to get element from list - ie. `row[0]``

Comment: @furas That makes sense but in this case the list is dynamic.  How do I increment that as I don't want row[0] all the time

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure how you'd do this in increments so you you could go driver.get -> action, driver.get -> action

Comment: @furas Nevermind that works.  I'm not sure I understand why but that works.  row[0] increasing by one increment.  Man I'm over complicating things LOL